# Read JSON-File with Java

Tags: java, json

I try to read to following JSON-File:

```json
[
  {
    "0": {
      "owner_ip": 0,
      "id": 0,
      "text": "test",
      "timestamp": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "1": {
      "owner_ip": 0,
      "id": 1,
      "text": "test",
      "timestamp": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "2": {
      "owner_ip": 0,
      "id": 2,
      "text": "test",
      "timestamp": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "3": {
      "owner_ip": 0,
      "id": 3,
      "text": "test",
      "timestamp": ""
    }
  },
  {
    "4": {
      "owner_ip": 0,
      "id": 4,
      "text": "test",
      "timestamp": ""
    }
  }
]
```

I imported the following package's:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.parser.ParseException;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;
```

I want to get the value of "0"->"text", I execute the following operation:

```js
JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

try(FileReader reader = new FileReader("filename"){
    Object obj = jsonParser.parse(reader);
    JSONArray readList = (JSONArray) obj;
    System.out.println(readList);
    System.out.println(readList.get(0));
    System.out.println(readList.get(0).getClass().getName());
    // Output = {"0":{"owner_ip":0,"id":0,"text":"test","timestamp":""}}
    // Output = org.json.simple.JSONObject
```

After this I don't know how to code further. I try a lot of different ways, but nothing works. I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JSON is oddly formatted. It has an array of objects and those objects have one entry with the same key as the index they have in the loop.

The JSON path of the `text` entry of the first element would be

```
json[0]["0"].text
```

You see `0` twice because you need to first select the first element of the array and then the object with key `"0"` within that array.

In your code you can do it like this:

```
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(reader);
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) array.get(0);
JSONObject nestedObj = (JSONObject) obj.get("0");
String textValue = (String) nestedObj.get("text");
System.out.println(textValue);
```

Though I would recommend to fix the format of your JSON. That nested object seems completely unnecessary.

Ultimately your JSON would look like this:

```
[
  {
    "owner_ip": 0,
    "id": 0,
    "text": "test",
    "timestamp": ""
  },
  {
    "owner_ip": 0,
    "id": 1,
    "text": "test",
    "timestamp": ""
  },
  {
    "owner_ip": 0,
    "id": 2,
    "text": "test",
    "timestamp": ""
  },
  {
    "owner_ip": 0,
    "id": 3,
    "text": "test",
    "timestamp": ""
  },
  {
    "owner_ip": 0,
    "id": 4,
    "text": "test",
    "timestamp": ""
  }
]
```

Then you can skip the `obj.get("0")` line in the code.

```
JSONArray array = (JSONArray) jsonParser.parse(reader);
JSONObject obj = (JSONObject) array.get(0);
String textValue = (String) obj.get("text");
System.out.println(textValue);
```

Comment: __Your JSON is oddly formatted__

How is it correct?

Answer (score -1):

If you are sure that the structure remains the same,

```
JSONArray readList = (JSONArray) obj;
JSONObject targetObj = readList.get(0);
System.out.println(targetObj.get("text")); // will print "test"
```

Or you can iterate throw the JSONArray.

Comment: ```lang-js
JSONObject targetObj = (JSONObject)readList.get(0); // I get an error with (JSONObject)
System.out.println(targetObj.getString("text"));  // In this line, i get an error, now.
```
I get the following error:
__Error:(180, 41) java: cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method getString(java.lang.String)
  location: variable targetObj of type org.json.simple.JSONObject__

Comment: My bad, try 'get("text")' instead of 'getString("text")'